# Ignore a unique role with custom key - Laravel - Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In my project with **Laravel 5.6** and **MongoDB**, to validate my inputs in an update method, I use a validator like below,

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'string|max:255',
            'phone' => 'string|valid_phone',
            'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255',
                Rule::unique('admins','email')->ignore($id),
            ],
            'password' => 'string|min:6',
            'access' => 'numeric',
        ]);
```

I want the field to be unique and ignore the same email for the user with special `$id`.

Everything looks Ok! But when I call my route to update my user and pass the current email of the user as email, It returns a validator error like this,

```
"email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
```

So, the unique validation did not work correctly!

I also have been set the `$primaryKey='_id';` in my user model.

What's the problem? Have I missed something?

Comment: Install [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see what kind of query is produced in order to check the uniqueness.

Comment: thank you for introducing the debugbar:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `$primaryKey='_id'` in user model you should set second parameter in `ignore` method. Below is a quote from documentation:

> If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may
>   specify the name of the column when calling the ignore method

```
 Rule::unique('admins','email')->ignore($id,'_id')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75588372/14344959